# How to validate PUT requestBody for NotNull constraints only when the object key is passed

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, request, notnull

I am using Spring @RequestBody, and I want to use @NotNull constraints only on the keys which are present in request otherwise, not throw any error.

```
public class Test {
    private List<String> a;
    private String b;
}
```

eg 1. No Error

```
{
  b = "1"
}
```

eg 2. Error B cannot be null

```
{
  b = null
}
```

eg 3. Error A cannot be null

```
{
  a = null,
  b = "1"
}
```

I can use @NotNull constraints but that makes the keys required. I dont want the keys to be required as there are cases in which I only want to post body with { b : "1" }.

Comment: I don't understand the difference between 1 and 3 in terms of the Java object. The corresponding Java object will be exactly the same and thus you will not be able to differentiate between the two examples at validation time. You would need to validate the JSON itself.

Comment: I think a custom validator will do a better job.

Comment: Yes @FahimFahad , used custom validator as well, but the only issue is method is unable to differentiate between null and unset values.

Answer (score 0):

Jackson provides an annotation that can be used on class level (@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true).

Comment: Thanks @Abhay. But still getting error due to @NotNull constraint when not passing it in request.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Test {

    @NotNull
    private List<String> a;
    @NotNull
    private String b;
}
```
Request : { "b" : "1"} -> Getting error when A is unset in request.